# What happens if I "sleep" windows 10 while programs are running?

Tags: windows-10, sleep

Suppose I click "sleep" to windows 10, I'm wondering for example, suppose these programs were busy at the moment of sleep, for example:

*Google drive uploading a recently locally edited file.

*a program running a process, such as a program calculating PI, or a video editor rendering.

What happens to this processes? Do they have to finish before sleeping? Do all the information saved to start from the same point when awake? Do they have to get killed before sleeping?

Comment: If you put Windows to sleep then your CPU is in a sleep power state.  This means it cannot process any instructions.  You should do more researched because most of your questions are single word answers.

Comment: @Ramhound I think he knows that part. He's saying since the cpu can't do any calculations in sleep mode, how is the process saved in a state to which it can easily resume later